# Using a dynamic 2D array or a hashmap in pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm, networking, data-structures, pseudocode

I have a networking algorithm, I should have a structure to store the location of each node at each clock tick. The number of nodes is not a priory known since a new node can join the network at any time. Also, the set of clock ticks is not a priori known and as time goes by new entries for clock ticks are added.

To store this information in my pseudcode, I have two choices:

1. using a dynamic two dimensional array and have something like:

   ```
   array[i][t]=location of node i at time t
   ```
2. using a two dimensional hashmap and have something like:

   ```
   map.set(i,t,location of node i at time t)
   ```

where i and t are both keys for the hash map.

But in both cases I do not know how can I go through all the elements of the structure in pseudo-code since I do not know the range of clock ticks and the nodes. I think I can store the ID of every node that is added and every clock tick in two different sets but I think there should be a wiser way to do this.

So, if I use a 2D array, I would like to have something like:

```
For all i in (set of node IDs for which we have stored locations)
    For all t in (set of times for which we have stored locations)
        if x < array[i][t] then return true,
```

and if I use the hash map,

```
    For all i in (set of node IDs for which we have stored locations)
        For all t in (set of times for which we have stored locations)
             if x < map.get(i,t) then return true,
```

which structure is preferable and how can I go through all elements in a **wiser way, i.e., a way that is short since I have not much space (preferably not adding additional variables such as two sets for storing clock ticks and node IDs) and easy to understand**? of course, solutions that care about memory use or speed of retrieval are welcome as long as they can be written in a short and easy to understand pseudocode.

Comment: Why not just `for each location in map/array`? It's just pseudo-code. You can write whatever you see fit.

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks for your comment, I edited and added what I mean by wiser way at the end od my question.

Answer (score 1):

First, have an array of tick times. This gives you a mapping from consecutive, integer valued "tick indices" to corresponding tick times.

For each node, store the tick index at which they joined the network.

Also for each node, store an array of location samples, one for each tick since they joined.

(This per-node information can be stored in a map from nodeID to node data.)

Iterating through all the location samples is simple: just iterate through the nodes, and for each node iterate through its location samples. The position of each location sample within the node's array, coupled with the base tick index for the node, will allow you to associate that location sample with its corresponding tick time.

This approach minimizes memory usage, avoids the memory indirections which hash tables are prone to, and allows easy iteration and lookups along any dimension.